Custom Exception handler after max retry attempts for resilience4j-retry spring annotation
Kinda what the title says, I have a method with @Retry on it and a retry configuration. However I am not able to find a way to do a custom error method to default to once all retry attempts are completed. As of now it is just a very base level configuration as shown below.
application.yml
resilience4j.retry:
  configs:
    hydration:
      maxRetryAttempts: 6
      waitDuration : 10000

Code annotation
@Retry(name = "hydration")
public void hydrateCaches() {
...
}

